# Merge two search results in Outlook 2007

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

it's possible to combine two search criteria in Outlook 2007 and merge all result ?

Example:

Emails sent from email1 to email2

plus all

sent from email2 to email1

excluding all other messages that do not meet the criteria above.

I've tried enabling query builder and using search folders with no luck.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If someone would ever run into this:
Yes, it is. This is a built in, but hidden feature called "Query Builder".

This article explains how to enable it:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307922

Here's how it would look like:
http://blog.techhit.com/55738-using-outlook-querybuilder-to-define-advanced-criteria-for-search-folders-and-advanced-find

It worked for me in Outlook 2013 too.